# How to use GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean extension in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

In iOS5, apple have added an extension named 'GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean' to help developers to implement occlusion culling.

I try to use it in my code, but I totally do not know how to use it.

These are my questions:

1. Should I implement querying and getting result in same frame or in two frames?
2. How to draw the bounding box?
3. Should I switch to off-screen rendering before querying? if so, how should I do in order to achieve the off-screen rendering?

I have found a possible answer of this, but the code [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598368/iphone-ios5-querying-opengl-es-2-0-pipeline-objects-if-they-are-hidden-in-the-vi) is not very clear and missing some key code of using this extension.

Comment: now, question 1 & 3 is already solved, but I still don't know how to draw the bounding box of objects...

Comment: Would you mind updating this with an answer to what you found?

Comment: @Xavier We should have an FBO for display, so we need create a new FBO for off-screen rendering. Before querying, we should switch to the off-screen FBO(just binding), and after querying we switch back to the main FBO. Then we can draw the object based on the query result.